# How can I detect if a screen size gets changed in Angular if I hide an element?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently developing a contact form. If the form gets submitted successfully, I'm hiding it. The problem is that in this case the footer comes up because the contact form is hidden:

```
<div class="form-wrapper mat-elevation-z1" [hidden]="successfullySent">
    .....
</div>
```

I've already developed a script that fixes this problem but the script only works on window resize changes and is part of my footer component:

```
onResize() {
  this.stickyFooter();
}
```

So does anyone has an idea how I can call this script from my contact component or detect the change of the DOM in the footer component somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` in this case

```
hideItem = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

When your div hide, you call `this.hideItem.next(successfullySent);`

and subscribe in onResize as

```
this.hideItem.subscribe(successfullySent=>{
            // if successfullySent
})
```

Comment: Why would you use `string` as opposed to `boolean`?

Comment: I've got it working now but the problem is that the script is getting called to early when the variable got changed but the DOM takes some mil. seks. to get changed. Any idea? I've proved it by adding a 5 sec. timeout before the execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter for your `successfullySent`

```js
class Component {
  set successfullySent(v: boolean) {
    this._successfullySent = v;
    if (v) {
      this.stickyFooter(); // or this.onResize();
    }
  }

  get successfullySent(): boolean {
    return this._successfullySent;
  }

  private _successfullySent: boolean;
}
```